# Detect when user is done typing in a UITextField within a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield, swift2

I have a `UITextField` embedded within a `UITableViewCell`. I am trying to implement a feature similar to Instagram's commenting where when the user has text in the textfield the send button is enabled, and if there is no text the send button is not enabled. I can't seem to detect when the user is done typing even when having implemented `textFieldDidEndEditing`. This method only seems to work if the return button is clicked. Is there a way to detect when the user is done typing in the textfield and has at least one character, thereby enabling the send button?

My code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 ...
case .comment:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellInfo.description, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PictureInformationTableViewCell
            cell.sendMessageBtn.addTarget(self, action: "didTapSendMessageBtn:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            cell
            cell.commentTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1
            cell.commentTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
            cell.sendMessageBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            if initBtn == false {
                cell.sendMessageBtn.enabled = false
            }
            buttonColor = cell.sendMessageBtn.tintColor
            cell.commentTextField.delegate = self
            //cell.commentTextField.addTarget(self, action: "didEndEditing:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.e)
            return cell
        }


func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(PictureInformation.comment.description, forIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 3)) as! PictureInformationTableViewCell
     if let text = textField.text {
         initBtn = true
         if text.characters.count > 0 {
             cell.sendMessageBtn.enabled = true
             cell.sendMessageBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
             tableView.reloadInputViews()
         } else {
             cell.sendMessageBtn.enabled = false
             cell.sendMessageBtn.setTitleColor(buttonColor, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
             tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 3)], withRowAnimation: .None)
             tableView.reloadInputViews()
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the action `EditingChanged` for your `textField` that action is called whenever you add a value to your `textField`.

**Update**
I have added a textField and a button in my storyboard. I have created two outlets, one for the button and one for the textField and I have added an action for my textField (EditingChanged).

The only thing you need to do now to enabled/disable the button is:

```
@IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var txtField: UITextField!

@IBAction func txtField_EditingChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
        if txtField.text?.characters.count > 0{
            btn.enabled = true
        }
        else{
            btn.enabled = false
        }
    }
```

Comment: in place of ```textFieldDidEndEditing```?

Comment: You can have both if you want, but I think it´s enough with EditingChanged, so yes replace those if you don´t need the other one.

Comment: Throwing an error when I delete characters from the text field (perhaps too quickly for the method to keep up?): ```Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 0 from section 3, but there are only 3 sections before the update'```

Comment: Actually it throws that error when I try to delete the last character from the text field

Comment: Weird... Did you remove the old action both form the code your story board? Try to delete all the actions from both your code and your storyboard and then just add EditingChanged action for your textField. I just tried, works perfect for me. Try to add the EditingChanged and just a print("Changed") in it and check if it works and then add your code.

Comment: It's my fault I did replace ```textFieldDidEndEditing``` with ```EditingChanged```. The problem was ```tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 3)], withRowAnimation: .None)``` when the count is equal to 0. That was unnecessary.

Comment: I'm having trouble re-enabling the button. I'm clicking it and it's not responding when there is text in the field. The return values of ```cell.sendMessageBtn.enabled``` look correct after ```tableView.reloadInputViews()``` but the button isn't enabling.

Comment: Try to remove and add the button again from your storyboard.

Comment: It looks like it's pointing to a different UIButton object each time text is entered or deleted.

Comment: I have didEndEditing in my controller instead of UITableCellView. I created a variable to store the button when the view first loads and used that button in didEndEditing and that fixed the problem.

Comment: No need for two outlets. You can change sender:AnyObject to sender: UITextField use btn.enabled = sender.text!.characters.count > 0